# TYPO3 TCA - Display or hide tabs at treelevel

Tags: typo3

For an project, I have extended the TYPO3 TCA with a extra extension, named "project_extends". Now, I have all new TCA Objects - sorted in tabs - on every Treepoint/Contentpage, to configurate some fluid templates or extensions.

For example: I have three tabs, named "Tab1","Tab2" and "Tab3".
Now I want to display Tab1 and Tab3 at the second tree-level of the contentpages, but not at level one.

I don't found a understandable solution via google & co and hope here of helpful solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

That's simple, to hide whole tab you just need to disable ALL fields which are visible on it.

To do this open page properties, find `Page TSconfig` field and for each field you want to disable add something like this:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.list_type.disabled = 1
```

in this sample `tt_content` is a required table and `list_type` is the field. Normally (without above config) it should be visible as only field on the ***Plugin*** tab when inserting TT content with type ***Insert Plugin*** , however while you disabled it will be hidden and also tab will disappear.

Tip: you can recognize these values using some browser inspection tool, i.e. FireBug of Firefox.

Comment: I was about to ask how to hide a whole tab ... thanks